# Can't read property 'emoji' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a ticket system with 5 different topics for people to make a ticket from, I have most of the code down but when the bot tries to get the collection for the emojis I get the error:

```
(node:43144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined
    at C:\Users\nalfo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\NetSync Beta\commands\ticket\ticket-create.js:171:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:43144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 5)
(node:43144) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've tried to replace the actual emojis with just the emoji names and stuff as well.
Here's the code that I am currently using:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const db = require('quick.db');
const ms = require("parse-ms");
const randomstring = require("randomstring");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (message.deletable) message.delete();
  let permembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor('#e64b0e')
  .setDescription(`An error occured: I don't have permission to manage channels.`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter(`© NetSync by Towncraft Developers`);

  if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) return message.channel.send(permembed).then(msg => { msg.delete(10000) });

  let user2 = message.author;

  let timeout = 300;

  let daily = await db.fetch(`ticketcooldown_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`);

  if (daily !== null && timeout - (Date.now() - daily) > 0) {
    let time = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - daily));

    **Embeds (Not Needed)**

  let topic1 = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}-topic1`)
  let topic2 = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}-topic2`)
  let topic3 = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}-topic3`)
  let topic4 = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}-topic4`)
  let topic5 = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}-topic5`)

  if(topic1 == null) topic1 = 'General Issues';
  if(topic2 == null) topic2 = 'Discord Issues';
  if(topic3 == null) topic3 = 'Server Issues';
  if(topic4 == null) topic4 = 'Submit a Report';
  if(topic5 == null) topic5 = 'Other';

  db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketnumber`, numbers)
  db.add(`${message.guild.id}-ticketcount`, 1)
  db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketopener`, message.author.username)
  db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketopener2`, message.author.username)
  db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.channel.id}-ticketopener3`, message.author.id)

  let user2 = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketopener2`)
  console.log(user2)

  let ticketcount = db.fetch(`${message.guild.id}-ticketcount`)

  **More Embeds (Not Needed)**

  let msg = await message.channel.send(input)
  await msg.react("1️⃣")// 1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣
  await msg.react("2️⃣")
  await msg.react("3️⃣")
  await msg.react("4️⃣")
  await msg.react("5️⃣")

  const filter = (reaction, user) => ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
  msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 10000
  }).then(collected => {
    const reaction = collected.first();
    switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
      case '1️⃣':
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic1)

      var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
    message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
      (chan) => {
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
         'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
          'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
        let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
        if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

      chan.setParent(category.id)
      chan.send(channelsend1)
      chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

      let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#e64b0e')
      .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

      let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
      logchannel.send(logchannelembed1)  
      message.channel.send(authorsend)
      msg.delete()
    });
    break;
    case '2️⃣':
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic2)

      var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
    message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
      (chan) => {
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
         'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
          'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
        let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
        if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

      chan.setParent(category.id)
      chan.send(channelsend2)
      chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

      let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#e64b0e')
      .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

      let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
      logchannel.send(logchannelembed2)  
      message.channel.send(authorsend)
      msg.delete()
      });
      break;
    case '3️⃣':
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic3)

      var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
    message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
      (chan) => {
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
         'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
          'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
        let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
        if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

      chan.setParent(category.id)
      chan.send(channelsend3)
      chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

      let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#e64b0e')
      .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

      let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
      logchannel.send(logchannelembed3)  
      message.channel.send(authorsend)
      msg.delete()
      });
      break;
      case '4️⃣':
        db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic4)

        var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
      message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
        (chan) => {
        chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
           'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
        })
        chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
            'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
        })
        chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
          let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
          if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

        chan.setParent(category.id)
        chan.send(channelsend4)
        chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
        db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

        let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#e64b0e')
        .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

        let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
        logchannel.send(logchannelembed4)  
        message.channel.send(authorsend)
        msg.delete()
        });
        break;
        case '5️⃣':
          db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic5)

          var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
        message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
          (chan) => {
          chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
             'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
          })
          chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
              'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
          })
          chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
            let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
            if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

          chan.setParent(category.id)
          chan.send(channelsend5)
          chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
          db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

          let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor('#e64b0e')
          .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

          let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
          logchannel.send(logchannelembed5)  
          message.channel.send(authorsend)
          msg.delete()
          });
          break;
      case '❌':
      db.subtract(`${message.guild.id}-ticketcount`, 1)
      msg.delete() 
      return message.channel.send(cancelembed)
    }
  })

    db.set(`ticketcooldown_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`, Date.now())
  }}

  module.exports.config = {
    name: "ticket-create",
    description: "Creates a new support ticket.",
    usage: "!ticket-create (topic)",
    accessableby: "Staff",
    aliases: ["ticket-open", "ticket-new"]
}
```

Line 171 is: `switch (reaction.emoji.name) {`

**Updated Code:**

```
  let msg = await message.channel.send(input)
  await msg.react("1️⃣")// 1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣
  await msg.react("2️⃣")
  await msg.react("3️⃣")
  await msg.react("4️⃣")
  await msg.react("5️⃣")

  const filter = (reaction, user) => ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
  msg.awaitReactions(filter, { time: 10000, errors: ["time"], max: 1 }).then(collected => { //Changed this to the new stuff
    const reaction = collected.first();
    switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
      case '1️⃣':
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic1)

      var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
    message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
      (chan) => {
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
         'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
          'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
        let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
        if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

      chan.setParent(category.id)
      chan.send(channelsend1)
      chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

      let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#e64b0e')
      .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

      let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
      logchannel.send(logchannelembed1)  
      message.channel.send(authorsend)
      msg.delete()
    });
    break;
    case '2️⃣':
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic2)

      var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
    message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
      (chan) => {
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
         'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
          'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
        let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
        if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

      chan.setParent(category.id)
      chan.send(channelsend2)
      chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

      let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#e64b0e')
      .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

      let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
      logchannel.send(logchannelembed2)  
      message.channel.send(authorsend)
      msg.delete()
      });
      break;
    case '3️⃣':
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic3)

      var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
    message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
      (chan) => {
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
         'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
          'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
      })
      chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
        let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
        if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

      chan.setParent(category.id)
      chan.send(channelsend3)
      chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
      db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

      let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor('#e64b0e')
      .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

      let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
      logchannel.send(logchannelembed3)  
      message.channel.send(authorsend)
      msg.delete()
      });
      break;
      case '4️⃣':
        db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic4)

        var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
      message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
        (chan) => {
        chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
           'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
        })
        chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
            'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
        })
        chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
          let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
          if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

        chan.setParent(category.id)
        chan.send(channelsend4)
        chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
        db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

        let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('#e64b0e')
        .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

        let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
        logchannel.send(logchannelembed4)  
        message.channel.send(authorsend)
        msg.delete()
        });
        break;
        case '5️⃣':
          db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-ticketreason`, topic5)

          var name = `ticket-${numbers}`;
        message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: "text" }).then(
          (chan) => {
          chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === '@everyone'), {
             'VIEW_CHANNEL': false
          })
          chan.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Staff'), {
              'VIEW_CHANNEL': true
          })
          chan.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {'VIEW_CHANNEL': true, 'SEND_MESSAGES': true, 'MENTION_EVERYONE': false})
            let category = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "⊱━≺ OPEN TICKETS ≻━━━━⊰" && c.type == "category");
            if(!category) return message.channel.send(categorysend)

          chan.setParent(category.id)
          chan.send(channelsend5)
          chan.setTopic(`Support Ticket ${numbers}`)
          db.set(`${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}-channelID`, chan.id)

          let authorsend = new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setColor('#e64b0e')
          .setDescription(`Ticket Created, #${chan.name}`)

          let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(cl => cl.name == "ticket-logs" && cl.type == "text")
          logchannel.send(logchannelembed5)  
          message.channel.send(authorsend)
          msg.delete()
          });
          break;
      case '❌':
      db.subtract(`${message.guild.id}-ticketcount`, 1)
      msg.delete() 
      return message.channel.send(cancelembed)
    }
  }).catch(collected => {
    msg.delete()  
    return message.channel.send(timeoutembed).then(msg => { msg.delete(10000) })
  })

    db.set(`ticketcooldown_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`, Date.now())
  }}
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: This is a big block of code, so if you could point to where the error is (line 171) that would be great.

Comment: `switch (reaction.emoji.name) {` is line 171, edited the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a time limit of 10 seconds but you don't define that a shortage of time is an error

So change the options to this

`{ time: 10000, errors: ["time"], max: 1 }`

If you don't define it as an error then it will go to the .then block, and in the then block you assume there is a reaction with the line code

`const reaction = collected.first();`

If you go this route you will need to add a `catch`  block

The other option is to check if reaction is defined, if not return.

Comment: For some reason this fixed it for a while, but it's putting the same error, I changed those things and added `.catch()` at the end of the switch.

Comment: Added the new code to the post, also put comments on the things changed.

Comment: inside the catch you did not do anything with the error, you should either log it or send a message that the time is up. Example: `.catch(err => console.error(err))`

Comment: I added one to send a timeout embed, but once the 5 reactions are added it instantly sends that embed and deletes the message.

Comment: After the 5 reactions are added it instantly removes it? It's possible that adding the reactions takes a long time and with a few extra seconds the time would be up. Also I have tried the relevant code and it looks like the reactions are only validated if all the reactions have been added. You are using special characters as well so that could cause some trouble

Comment: Correct after the 5 reactions the catch is fired deleting it and sending the timeout message. I've tried setting the time to 15000, 30000, and 60000 and the same result happens. How would I change from using the special characters? Would I just replace everything with the actual name of the emojis in discord? (e.g. "one," "two," etc.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215912/discussion-between-karizma-and-princebunbun981).